# How to display output for password minimum length in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, audit

My question is, how do I edit the script such that if password minimum length is greater or equals to 10 then it will display "Vulnerability: no"?

Thanks in advance. :)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhnh8.png)

**MY SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash

passminlen=`grep "^minlen /etc/security/pwquality.conf`
if [[ $passminlen == "minlen=10" ]]
then
isVulnerable="no"
else
isVulnerable="Yes"
fi
echo
echo "Audit Criteria: Password minimum length is 10 or greater"
echo "Vulnerability: $isVulnerable"
echo "Details: See Below"
echo
echo "Source of info:"
echo "grep ^minlen /etc/security/pwquality.conf
echo
echo "Output: $passminlen"
echo
echo "Remediation: "
echo "If password minimum length is lesser than 10 please edit the following under /etc/security/pwquality.conf."
echo
```

Comment: Add output of `grep "^minlen /etc/security/pwquality.conf` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk -F= '$1=="minlen" {print $2}' /etc/security/pwquality.conf` to get the minimum length as a plain number. The `-F=` tells `awk` to split lines on the "=" character, and the script checks whether field #1 (what's before the "=") is "minlen" and if so it prints field #2 (what's after the "=").

There are a couple of other things to watch for; first, minlen might not be defined, so you need to check for that. You *might* want to check for multiple definitions. Also, when doing numeric comparisons in bash, it's simplest to use `(( ))` instead of `[[ ]]`. And I recommend using `$( )` instead of backticks.

Something like this:

```
passminlen=$(awk -F= '$1=="minlen" {print $2}' /etc/security/pwquality.conf)

if [[ -z "$passminlen" ]]
then    # Minimum length is not defined
    isVulnerable="yes"

elif [[ "$passminlen" = *$'\n'* ]]
then    # Minimum length is multiply defined; this is weird
    isVulnerable="yes"

elif (( $passminlen" >= 10 ))
then
    isVulnerable="no"

else
    isVulnerable="Yes"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check the value of "minlen" in your conf file, so you should break the result of grep, taking only the value after `=`

E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash
passminlen="$(grep -e "^minlen" /etc/security/pwquality.conf)"
if [ "${passminlen#*=}" -ge 10 ]; then
  isVulnerable="no"
else
  isVulnerable="Yes"
fi
```

Note that:

- I preferred the `$(...)` command substitution instead of backquotes.
- I used [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in order to cut the output of grep.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for the link you gave for parameter expansion is what I needed as I have been trying to separate the value between minlen and =.